# Amazon SNS push notification self registration (Android)

Tags: android, push-notification, amazon-sns

How do register the device token (FCM registration) through the mobile app(Android)and create topic/subscription also through the app.

Comment: You have the entire blogpost on Amazon website about it, including the Java implementation on Android phone: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/mobile/mobile-token-management-with-amazon-sns/

Comment: Tq@MariuszBrona I got some flow. Is there any details about create topic and subscription through the app and will create push message from mobile app